# Defining AddYears, Calculating age in ten years using C#

Tags: c#, string, datetime, int

I'm new to C# and have been doing an exercise from a book. The exercise is to write a program that reads my age from the console and prints my age after ten years from now.

Here is the code I have written based on what I have understood so far.

```
namespace Page_108_Age
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Gives date of birth
            DateTime dob = new DateTime(1989, 10, 30, 23, 31, 00);

            //Gives current age
            DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
            int age = today.Year -dob.Year;
            if (today < dob.AddYears(age)) age--;

            //age plus ten years
            DateTime agePlusTen = age.AddYears(10);

            Console.WriteLine(age);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that AddYears in line 16

[`DateTime dobPlusTen = age.AddYears(10);`]

is giving me the following error...

> 'int' does not contain a definition for 'AddYears' and no extension
>   method 'AddYears' accepting a first argument of type 'int' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I'm obviously missing something but now sure what other then I think I need to define AddYears as it is not highlighted in my code as a struct.

**Note: apologies for the "dobPlusTen" as most of you picked up on this is short for date of birth plus ten years which is not what it is supposed to be as I want Current Age Plus Ten Years, I changed it to agePlusTen.**

Comment: `age` is `int`, not `DateTime`. The method `AddYears` is for `DateTime` objects.

Comment: Yes because you declared `age` as `int` either make it `DateTime` or add the 10 years in it with normal `+` operation

Comment: From the fact that you're doing exercises, and that a simple thing tripped you up, I'm going to assume you're new to coding. So in my opinion, one of the most important things you can take away from ALL of these answers is that there are always LOTS of ways to complete any given task. Figuring out which way is best for a given problem comes with experience; in this case, all the answers are pretty good, in my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write:

```
DateTime dobPlusTen = age.AddYears(10);
```

Doesn't this ring your bell?

Your variable is named `dobPlusTen`, yet the *value* you assign to it is *not* `dob` + 10.

So change it to

```
DateTime dobPlusTen = dob.AddYears(10);
```

and you'll be all right.

**EDIT** As per Ross Dargan's remark below this answer (I had failed to notice the exact question: *The exercise is to write a program that reads my age from the console and prints my age after ten years from now.*), it's actually much simpler.

Just a

```
var line = Console.ReadLine();
int agePlus10 = Convert.ToInt32(line) + 10;
Console.WriteLine(agePlus10);
```

will do.

Comment: note this still won't give you the correct answer as you are not actually using dobPlusTen you are outputting age. Also dob plus 10 will always make you ten years old :-)

Comment: Since `DateTime dob = new DateTime(1989, 10, 30, 23, 31, 00);`, adding 10 years to dob does not make `dobPlusTen` ten years old... And of course he should use `dobPlusTen` as output.

Comment: adding 10 years to dob would give a datetime of 30/10/1999 - when the OP would be exactly 10 years old :-)

Comment: @RossDargan, of course you are right, I've modified my answer... Thx!

Comment: Apologies for the confusion in the code reading "dobPlusTen", should be "agePlusTen", which makes more sense.

Answer (score 2):

Close :-)

Age is an int, so that method doesn't exist (it exists on DateTime). This should put you on the right track:-

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Gives date of birth
        DateTime dob = new DateTime(1989, 10, 30, 23, 31, 00);

        //Gives current age
        DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
        int age = today.Year -dob.Year;
        if (today < dob.AddYears(age)) age--;

        //age plus ten years
        age = age +10;

        DateTime agePlusTen = dob.AddYears(age);

        Console.WriteLine(agePlusTen.ToShortDateString());

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess there's a couple of ways to look at this.

First, age is an integer.  So it has no AddYears method.  You could just add 10 to it:

```
age += 10;
```

Or, if you want to use the AddYears method of the DateTime type, you'll need to do it using a DateTime variable.  Such as

```
DateTime dobPlusTen = dob.AddYears(10);
```

Answer (score 1):

I did the same exercise from Fundamentals of computer programming book.
In the solution and guide line for that question they asked to use the methods `Console.ReadLine()`, `int.Parse()` and `DateTime.AddYears()`, my solution sticking to those 3 methods:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter Age:");
string Age = Console.ReadLine();
int ma = int.Parse(Age);

DateTime today = DateTime.Now;

// add the 10 years to today's date
DateTime future = today.AddYears(10);

// add your age to future
DateTime futurYear = future.AddYears(ma);

// now subtract them to get your age in 10 years from now 
int fa = futurYear.Year - today.Year;

Console.WriteLine("\nIn 10 years you will be:");
Console.WriteLine(fa);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be sticking to using DateTime objects, since integers have no concepts of dates/years (as given by the error).  Instead do something like:

```
int yearsOld = (int)(today.Subtract(dob).TotalDays / 365);
```

This lets you work with TimeSpan objects, so you could get the exact age and not just an approximation.  You could just add 10 to this after.

EDIT:

Of course this isn't accounting for leap years, and I'm rounding down to the lower year, but perhaps you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

`age` is an `int` representing the number of years, not a `DateTime`. `AddYears` is a method that exists on `DateTime`, not `int`. You should either simply add `10` to the age, or add or subtract 10 years from a `DateTime` (add 10 to `today` or subtract 10 from `dob`; these are pretty much the same) to come up with the right number:

```
int agePlusTen = age + 10;

// or

DateTime tenYearsFromNow = today.AddYears(10);
int age = tenYearsFromNow.Year - dob.Year;
if (tenYearsFromNow < dob.AddYears(age)) age--;
```

Answer (score 0):

My version:

```
Console.WriteLine("Please, enter your age");
string age = Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("\nIn 10 years you will be:");
DateTime myNewAge = new DateTime(int.Parse(age));
Console.WriteLine(int.Parse(age) + 10);
```