# My program to add years to my age. Suggestions

Tags: c#, console-application

I'm working through a textbook that asks me to write a program that reads my age to the console and then adds x years to my age. I've seen some comments on this very topic and some suggestions. However, I'm trying to make my version more concise than what's been suggested. This is one good suggestion presented here by user BCol:

[Defining AddYears, Calculating age in ten years using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20952448/defining-addyears-calculating-age-in-ten-years-using-c-sharp)

I'm trying to do the same with fewer steps.  This is what my code looks like:

```
Console.WriteLine("Please, enter your age");
string age = Console.ReadLine();

DateTime myNewAge = new DateTime(int.Parse(age));
DateTime yearInFuture = myNewAge.AddYears(10);
Console.WriteLine(yearInFuture);
```

It's not working yet; I'm getting 01-Jan-11 12:00:00 AM after typing in my age and pressing enter. I'd really appreciate any suggestions and how to make it do the job correctly.  What am I missing? Is there another way to do it? I am self teaching C#.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: look at the `DateTime` constructor

Comment: Since you're using `int.Parse()`, it means you're entering your age in years. So why don't you just `Console.WriteLine(int.Parse(age) + 10)`?

Comment: thanks also to Grant and Plutonix

Answer (score 2):

The code below will take in two parameters and display the results on the console window.  The goal is to take in an age and increase that by the second parameter.

```
Console.WriteLine("Please, enter your age");
string age = Console.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine("Please, enter number of years to add.");
string addedYears = Console.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine(int.Parse(age) + int.Parse(addedYears));
```

Answer (score 1):

The

```
int.Parse(age)
```

returns a relatively small number, like 20 or 30, that represents the number of person's years of age.

But then you ask the `DateTime` constructor to make a date out of it and you use the constructor in a **wrong way**. You have chosen a constructor overload that takes an int

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2xf7zzk(v=vs.110).aspx

but according to the docs the number represents the ticks that have elapsed since 1st of January of the year 0001.

What date was 20 ticks later than the 1st January of 0001? I really believe it was still January 1st of 0001.

Do you get it now?

To fix this, you have to use another overload of the same constructor, probably the one that will allow you to pass the year rather than ticks.

Note however that there is no constructor that accepts the number of years (person's age). If a person is 20, you can't just pass 20, rather you have to pass 2015-20 as the date's year.

I am not going to present a solution as I believe there are far too many advices given already.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use :

```
Console.WriteLine(int.Parse(age) + 10);
```

Without creating any DateTime variables because it wont make much sense to mix between age and a point in time.

Comment: -1 from me as this is a bad answer. If person's age is 20 and you pass 20+10 as the year parameter in the constructor then apparently you will get a date in the year of 30.

Comment: @WiktorZychla well obviously if he's using DateTime then he means birth date or at least thats what I think it is. if not then why using DateTime at all.

Comment: Age and birth date are two distinct numbers. He clearly asks for age. If my age is 5 then my birth date is 2010. Just fix your answer.

Answer (score 0):

as some suggested here... 
if you only dealing with years you can work with `int` or a `double` instead of a `DateTime` object.

```
Console.WriteLine("Please, enter your age");
string age = Console.ReadLine();

int myNewAge; 
int.TryParse(age, out myNewAge);
int yearInFuture = myNewAge + 10;
Console.WriteLine(yearInFuture);
```

Obviously you should work with `try` `catch` and check for errors etc.

Answer (score 0):

Main idea is that if you want to increase your **`age`**, you should decrease the parsed date, as it must be far away from now, so you should simply add negative value in `AddYears` method. Also, you should add the `age` to current date, like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Please, enter your age");
string age = Console.ReadLine();

DateTime myNewAge = DateTime.Today.AddYears(-int.Parse(age) - 10);
Console.WriteLine(myNewAge);
```